# JOIN nested subquery returning NULL while updating calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to work around the "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" MySQL error, which means I've got a nested subquery (temp table). Note, I'm trying to get a `SELECT` to work before I move on to the actual `UPDATE`.

What I've got is a ledger table where I'm trying to find the associated row's calculated unit total using `active_units` (what the row started with) and with each additional adjustment in active units (there is one payment row and multiple adjustment rows in the same table that are associated by commission ID and schedule number). These are grouped by `month_num`. So if it's `active_units = 18` and there are three adjustment rows, one with `active_units_chg = -2`, then I should end up with `18 + -2 = 16`.

When I do this:

```
SELECT
   active_units
 , active_units_chg
 , active_units_total
 , CRM_commission_payments.active_units + (
    SELECT SUM(active_units_chg)
    FROM CRM_commission_payments AS cp
    WHERE cp.CRM_commissions_item_id = CRM_commission_payments.CRM_commissions_item_id
    AND cp.schedule_a_no = CRM_commission_payments.schedule_a_no
    AND cp.month_num = CRM_commission_payments.month_num
    AND cp.item_active = 1
) AS active_units_cal1
FROM CRM_commission_payments
WHERE CRM_commission_payments.payment_type = 'payment'
AND CRM_commission_payments.CRM_quotes_item_id = 2457
```

`active_units_cal1` is correct for the row. However, when I do this with a nested `JOIN`'d subquery, I get `NULL` for `active_units_calc.calc_chg`:

```
SELECT
   active_units
 , active_units_chg
 , active_units_total
 , CRM_commission_payments.active_units + (
    SELECT SUM(active_units_chg)
    FROM CRM_commission_payments AS cp
    WHERE cp.CRM_commissions_item_id = CRM_commission_payments.CRM_commissions_item_id
    AND cp.schedule_a_no = CRM_commission_payments.schedule_a_no
    AND cp.month_num = CRM_commission_payments.month_num
    AND cp.item_active = 1
) AS active_units_cal1
 , active_units_calc.calc_chg
FROM CRM_commission_payments
LEFT JOIN  (
     SELECT
        source.calc_chg
      , source.CRM_commissions_item_id
      , source.schedule_a_no
      , source.month_num
     FROM CRM_commission_payments AS cp1
     INNER JOIN (
          SELECT
             SUM(active_units_chg) AS calc_chg
           , cp.CRM_commissions_item_id
           , cp.schedule_a_no
           , cp.month_num
          FROM CRM_commission_payments AS cp
          WHERE cp.item_active = 1
     ) AS source
     WHERE source.CRM_commissions_item_id = cp1.CRM_commissions_item_id
     AND source.schedule_a_no = cp1.schedule_a_no
     AND source.month_num = cp1.month_num
) AS active_units_calc ON (
   active_units_calc.CRM_commissions_item_id = CRM_commission_payments.CRM_commissions_item_id
   AND active_units_calc.schedule_a_no = CRM_commission_payments.schedule_a_no
   AND active_units_calc.month_num = CRM_commission_payments.month_num
)
WHERE CRM_commission_payments.payment_type = 'payment'
AND CRM_commission_payments.CRM_quotes_item_id = 2457
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the top works as expected, if you pull out the left join query does it also return the expected results? it seems to be where it's hanging up.

Comment: The field subquery works regardless of whether the join subquery is there or not. The join subquery is really what I need to work.